# Getting Limited number of results from gridview/datasource?

Tags: asp.net, sql, caching, gridview

I have a gridview with a sql datasource. I have almost 35000 records which are being populated into the table. That usually hangs  the system while loading from the server.

Is there a way to get limited number of results at a time from the gridview or datasource.

Something like it loads the first 1000 results first .. once the user is done going through those results, then it loads the next 1000 results automatically.
I tried to use caching ...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString=""           SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1]" EnableCaching="true" CacheDuration="3000" >
```

I assume this caches the data and all the other sql queries remain local to the cache instead of going to the database. But when I refresh the page, it loads all the records again and takes the same amount of time(a minute).
So thats why I need something like loading the first 1000 records or something first.

Answer (score 0):

You could design your query according to GridView page size. Let suppose You are at page 1 of Gridview and page size is set to 100. Then just select first 100 records from the database.

Answer (score 0):

For your gridview enable paging and specify page size property

```
AllowPaging="true" 
PageSize="100"
```

Your gridview should be something like this in aspx page

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100"
```

Comment: this just displays 100 records on the gridview.How do I go to the next 100?